# Postgresql dead tuples not being removed

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

We are using Postgresql 9.4 in our app and some table's dead tuples are not being properly removed. We have autovacuum on, with the default configuration.
Here are some logs (this goes on the entire day):

```
< 2021-11-30 00:31:30.703 EST >LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "erp.public.example_table": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 71343 remain
    tuples: 0 removed, 2106528 remain, 1133145 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 62922 hits, 103385 misses, 172 dirtied
    avg read rate: 2.413 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.004 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 1.24s/0.82u sec elapsed 334.71 sec

< 2021-11-30 00:48:10.794 EST >LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "erp.public.example_table": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 71343 remain
    tuples: 0 removed, 2107145 remain, 1133466 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 62876 hits, 103433 misses, 75 dirtied
    avg read rate: 2.998 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.002 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 1.15s/0.73u sec elapsed 269.55 sec

< 2021-11-30 00:58:27.625 EST >LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "erp.public.example_table": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 71343 remain
    tuples: 0 removed, 2107347 remain, 1133476 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 62876 hits, 103433 misses, 14 dirtied
    avg read rate: 2.419 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 1.18s/0.85u sec elapsed 333.99 sec

< 2021-11-30 01:39:59.626 EST >LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "erp.public.example_table": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 71343 remain
    tuples: 0 removed, 2107627 remain, 1133724 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 62857 hits, 103454 misses, 44 dirtied
    avg read rate: 2.446 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.001 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 1.28s/0.83u sec elapsed 330.44 sec

< 2021-11-30 01:52:16.303 EST >LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "erp.public.example_table": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 71343 remain
    tuples: 0 removed, 2107741 remain, 1133724 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 62878 hits, 103431 misses, 3 dirtied
    avg read rate: 2.426 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 0.75s/0.78u sec elapsed 333.01 sec

< 2021-11-30 02:33:24.258 EST >LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "erp.public.example_table": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 71343 remain
    tuples: 0 removed, 2107731 remain, 1133919 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 62880 hits, 103447 misses, 32 dirtied
    avg read rate: 3.414 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.001 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 1.09s/0.71u sec elapsed 236.70 sec
```

As you can see, the vacuum is taking at least 200 sec and not removing any tuple.
This is happening with other tables as well. Already check for the common causes:

- Long running transactions
- Prepared transactions that did not get committed.
- Stale replication slots.

But none of these apply to our case

Comment: It must be one of these three causes, or data corruption (but that would give you an error in the log).

Comment: What is full version of instance e.g. 9.4.x? FYI, 9.4 is almost a year past EOL.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the version is 9.4.24 
We are migrating to 13

Comment: Well 9.4.26 and 9.4.26 have fixes for vacuum and logical replication, so it might not hurt to the minor upgrade to *.26. Have there been any crashes lately?

Comment: Yes we had crashes on the last week. Also today we had a problem were randon queries were getting slow for a short period of time, so I'm guessing that it could be due to a heavy process on the database (maybe autovacuum).

Comment: If the Postgres log is still available what did it show as the cause of the crashes? Also what did it show when it restarted after the crashes, in the way of errors? I'm going to say it is a pretty safe bet that the crashes and your present problems are connected.